# angular2-material 2 icons are not shown

Tags: angular, angular2-material

I am working on an Angular 2 project, using Material 2. For some reason icons are not shown, just what's supposed to be the "key" of the icon as text.

app.module:

```
  ...    
    import {MdButtonModule} from "@angular2-material/button";
    import {MdIconModule, MdIconRegistry} from "@angular2-material/icon";
    ...

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent,... CollapseableComponent],
      imports: [... MdButtonModule, MdIconModule, MdInputModule],
      providers: [{
        provide: LocationStrategy,
        useClass: HashLocationStrategy
      }, ... MdIconRegistry],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {

    }
```

index.html:

```
...
    <link href=”https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel=”stylesheet”>
  </head>
...
```

I tried several ways:

```
  <button md-fab> <md-icon>add</md-icon></button>
    <button md-fab> <md-icon class="md-elevation-z1">create</md-icon></button>
    <button md-icon-button>add</button>
```

I guess I tried about 5 more permutations, but all with the same result. I see the button, but with text on it. Just the icon alone also did not display in any of these approaches.

Answer (score 7):

You should be using [@angular/material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material) now, @angular2-material is deprecated. See [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1)

app.module:

```
    import {MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent,... CollapseableComponent],
      imports: [... MaterialModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [{
        provide: LocationStrategy,
        useClass: HashLocationStrategy
      }, ...],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {

    }
```

Just also noticed that you are using `”` instead of `"` in your CSS link for the font.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Plunker:
http://embed.plnkr.co/lAXjoXHZ4YdNgDOMUjPB/

Comment: Hey, many thanks for pointing the deprecation out! I also just found that wrong character copy-and-paste problem. That was the root oft he issue. An embarrassing one. Cheers!

Comment: @WernerWiking

I'm glad that helped you, I always check the change logs on GitHub on every new release to see what's new it can really help when the documentation is lacking because of the Alpa stage.

If you believe this is the correct answer please mark as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Comment: MaterialModule is now deprecated

Comment: @epiphanatic Yes that's correct, still currently usable but with a deprecation warning. You're more than welcome to edit my answer with the latest guidelines, I will make the correct changes when i'm at a computer if not.

Answer (score 0):

As J J B pointed out, the particular issue on this one was a wrong kind of quotes when including the google css in the index.html (that was a copy-paste error).

More important thing to take away is the other thing J J B said - @angular2-material is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
We have to follow the steps in ng2-image-viewer  

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-image-viewer

After complete those steps, we have to include material icons link in index.html

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

//For Material icons add code in style.css file They taken Opacity as 0 we can override to 1 then icons will display

.inline-icon > div > .tooltip:first-child {
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .options-image-viewer > .tooltip {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    pointer-events: visible !important;
  }

  .inline-icon, .image-gallery-2 {
    background-color: #222B38 !important;
  }

Wow, It's working fine.............
```